# do { } while(0) vs. if (1) { } in macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)

When one needs to execute multiple statements within preprocessor macro, it's usually written like

```
#define X(a) do { f1(a); f2(a); } while(0)
```

so when this macro is used inside expressions like:

```
if (...)
    X(a);
```

it would not be messed up.

The question is: wherever I've seen such expression, it's always `do { ... } while(0);`. Is there any reason to prefer such notion over (in my opinion more clear one) `if (1) { ... }`? Or am I wrong in my observations and they are equally popular?

Comment: `#define ever (;;)` then `for ever { ... }`

Comment: @KingsIndian the Q you linked to asked *why* such statements exist at all. aland here wants to know why one is preferable to the other, I think that's a perfectly valid, and also different question.

Comment: @penelope Moreover if I say dup, then it's not going to become dup right away. `At least 4 other people have to agree with me` and also it can be re-opened if community thinks all 5 close-voters got it wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, you're not wrong.

There's actually a nice reason:

```
#define my_code if (1) { ... }

if (1)
    my_code;
```

The problem is with the `;` ! It shouldn't be there... and that would just look strange and not in the spirit of the language. You can either choose to have a code that expands in to two `;` in a row, or a code that looks *un-c-ish* :)

On the other hand, the `do-while` construction does not have that problem.

---

Also, as others mentioned, there's an `else` problem:

```
if (1)
    my_code;
else { ... }
```

Ignoring the `;` issuse, the `else` block now belongs to the wrong if.

Answer (score 7):

`if` can be as safe as `do/while` only if there is `else` branch. E.g.:

```
#define X(a) if(1) { f1(a); f2(a); } else{}
```

Is as safe as:

```
#define X(a) do { f1(a); f2(a); } while(0)
```

So that the user can't do:

```
X(...) else ...;
```

One difference is that when using `do/while` it requires a `;` at the end, whereas `if/else` doesn't.

Comment: your solution still has the `;` issue - you could use it in code as `if (condition) X(a)` without `;`, it would not force the user to end his statements, producing wired un-semicolon-ed code

Comment: I'd say `if{}else{}` is more universal because it can be used with or without `;`. Personally, I don't like macros looking like plain code, so I prefer no `;` after a macro.

Comment: I'm accepting penelope's answer since it covers both differences between two cases in question. No offence meant.

Comment: No worries, it's your question.

Comment: I don't think `if (x) X(a); else doSomethingElse();` will work if `X(a)` uses the `if(1){..}else{}` form, but it will work just fine with the `do{...}while(0)` form.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this:

```
if(foo)
    X(a);
else
    whatever();
```

This would expand to:

```
if(foo)
    if(1) { ... }
else
    whatever();
```

Which is bad because now the else belongs to the wrong if.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10720525/412080

Answer (score 2):

Using `do... while` allows you to `break` out if necessary.

Comment: break out of what? he wants to use/not use `do-while` as a *macro*

Comment: To break out the body of the macro early if necessary. It's used all over the place in the linux source codes.

Comment: To me, just a half-scentence explanation looks a bit confusing and unocnvincing. Could you add a code snippet that demonstrates your point?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `#define X(a) do { ... } while(0)` form, it forces you to put `;` at the end of the statement `X(1)`.