# C - do{..} while(0); can be removed from code excluding usage nested if else?

Tags: c++, c

**do{...} while(0);**

the usage of **do{}while(0);** in my coding is used because, i do not want to use long if else nested conditional statements. I eventually give an break at the time of failure and move out of the loop, with a assurance that my function would have been traversed at least 1 time.

Now, the problem comes with the code warning tools, I am getting a warning at the usage of **do{...}while(0);**

the usage of **nested if(){} else{}** is less readable, high complex. and lets the code to be having dead code.

if i exclude **nested if(){} else{}** and **do{} while(0);** , do we left part with some other way to make code readable with understandable logic;

```
if(status_of_funcA_ok != funcA())
{ //failure}
else if (status_of_funcB_ok != funcB())
{//failure}
else if (status_of_funcC_ok != funcC())
else
{//Great}

do{
   if(status_of_funcA_ok != funcA())
   break;
   if (status_of_funcB_ok != funcB())
   break;
   if (status_of_funcC_ok != funcC())
   break;

  }while(0);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720465/do-while0-vs-if-1-in-macros
has not explained much to the problem, and has now got close. :(

Comment: could u give a concrete example of a part of your code plz? maybe it is possible to rewrite it differently

Comment: Compilers can warn about anything they like; it's impractical to avoid all warnings in all cases. *Most* warnings are important, but if you know what you're doing (i.e., you actually know better than the compiler in this case), you can ignore them.

Comment: I gave an example! hope it would be much understandable.

Answer (score 5):

Move the complete logic of the `do while{0}` loop to a function, and replace the `break` with `return`. And call the function, instead of the loop.

1. You will not have to worry about the beauty.
2. The compiler also doesn't have to complain about the `do while{0}`.

All the more, by adding a bit of modularity, the program might be a little more readable.

In any case, before doing this, it would be nice to check whether your compiler is in an *extremely pedantic* mode, and you might want to turn that off. That might take the warning away.

ss.

PS: You don't seem to need a return value for the function, but you could have that to get a clue of which function was successful.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this pattern too, for those who wonder, here's an abstract example:

```
do   // while(0) for break
{ 
  state1 = 0;
  if (cond1())
  {
    if (cond2())
      break;
    state1 = opA();
  }

  if (cond3() || state1 && state1->cond4())
    break;
  ... 
  Triumph(state1, ...);
  // often here: return
}
Failure(state1, ...);
```

I consider this valid in the following circumstances:

- you have a long-ish sequence (say, >~half a dozen of conditions)
- the conditions are complex, and you use / build up significant state, so you can't 
  isolate the elements into functions
- you are in an exception-unfriendly environment, or your `break`-ing code path is 
  not actually an exception

What you can do about it:

**Silence the warning.** It is just a warning, after all; <strike>and I don't see a "typical mistake" (like typing 0 instead of your condition) that would be caught by this warning.</strike>

*[edit] Now, that was silly. the typical mistake that you catch with the warning is e.g. `while (a1!=a1)` instead of `while (a1!=a2)`.[/edit]*

**Break into functions, move state to a class**
this would transform above code to:

```
struct Garbler
{
  State1 state1;

  bool Step1()
  {
     state1 = 0;
     if (cond1())
     {
        if (cond2())
          return false;
        state1 = opA();
     }
     return true;
  }

  bool Step2()
  {
     return cond3() || state1 && state1->cond4();
  }
  .. 

  void Run()
  {
    if (Step1() && Step2() && ... && Step23())
      Triumph(state1, ...);
    else
      Failure(state1, ...);
  }
}
```

This is arguably less readable, worse is that you pull apart the sequence, which might lead to a very questionable class (where members may be called only in a certain order).

**[Scopeguards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Scope_Guard)**
This may allow to transform the breaks into early returns, which are more acceptable:

```
state1 = 0;
ScopeGuard gFailure = MakeGuard(&Failure, ByRef(state1), ...);
if (cond1())
{
   if (cond2())
     return;
   state1 = opA();
}

if (cond3() || state1 && state1->cond4())
  return;

// everything went ok, we can dismiss the scopeguard
gFailure.Dismiss();
Triumph(state1, ...);
```

They can be more elegantly written in C++0x, preserve the flow, but the solution isn't that flexible either, e.g. when `Failure()` cannot be isolated easily into a single function.

Comment: A very precise and full answer. My habits are (more-or-less) the same. I have exactly the same habits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goto` instead of `do {} while(0)` and `break`. This is not readable and not good practice either though. I think for each specific case there is a better way to avoid deep if/else structures. For example, sometimes using function calls can help:

for example instead of:

```
if(status_of_funcA_ok != funcA())
{ //failure}
else if (status_of_funcB_ok != funcB())
{//failure}
else if (status_of_funcC_ok != funcC())
else
{//Great}
```

you can write:

```
if (check_funcs() == 0) {
   great();
}

int check_funcs() {
   if (status_of_funcA_ok != funcA())
     return -1;
   if (if(status_of_funcB_ok != funcB())) 
     return -2;
   if (if(status_of_funcC_ok != funcC())) 
     return -3;
   return 0; /* great */
}
```

Sometimes, you can use `exit()`.

Also, in c++ you can use `throw()` and `try/catch`:

```
try {
   /* */
  throw (this error);
   /* */
  throw (that error);
} catch (this error) {
} catch (that error) {
}
```

Comment: throw() and catch() should be reserved for exceptional circumstances only (exceptions). it is bad practice to use them as flow control structures.

Comment: thanks, for the reply.. I think goto/return would have been a better option but .. the foolish nasty tool has these things also as an warning. as **multiple break, usage of goto.**

as i am using C, throw and catch would not be applicable, 


i can use sub helper function pointers which will be wrapping up each condition, within a loop i can run these functions. 
but for small functions of more or less 4 to 5 conditional check, but does this approach acceptable in embedded programming is a serious doubt as i am very new to industry.

Comment: @bancsy: They are flow control structures *in principle*, how else can you use them if not to control flow? They should used to escape code paths where it's not meaningful to continue, whether or not that can happen a lot depends on your situation. Often you can have a function that checks for the preconditions that will cause your processing function to throw and returns a boolean, so you can opt-out of exceptions, in a way.

Comment: `goto` ain't good in C++ if objects with c'tor/d'tor are present, raw jumping may bypass them.

Comment: you are correct sir, this question is much related to C @valdo

Comment: @valdo: most newer compiler revisions won't compile code with `goto` that will cause problems with ctors/dtors (as fw as a few other cases).

Comment: @GManNickG: I guess a more appropriate wording of the second sentence should be: "It is bad practice to use them as replacement for if-else."

Comment: @Valdo: [Goto does not leak resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334952/will-using-goto-leak-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Nested nested if-else statements can become quite unreadable, but I think using do {..} while(0); as a replacement would be much worse. It is very unconventional and anybody else reading it would not really associate it with if-else statements.

There are a few things you can do to make nested if-else statements more readable. A few suggestions are:

1. optimize your logic - sometimes you can do away with a lot of if clauses when you 'refactor' your logic ex. grouping identical items.
2. use switch() - switch is generally more readable compared to if-else statements. You can associate an enum to each case and you can switch this.
3. encapsulate complicated logic with functions

Answer (score 0):

If there are more conditions to check avoid using `if{} else{},`

best practice is to Replace if else conditions with `switch case`